# Rudin 3.49 Cauchy Product

Tags: real-analysis

In rudin, it is introduced that with $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^na_k$, $B_n = \sum_{k=0}^nb_k$, and $C = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k$. (ex: $c_2 = a_0b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0$). I don't see why $C_n \neq A_nB_n$. I don't know what trivial fact I'm overlooking.

Comment: A simple counterexample will suffice: $A_1B_1=(a_0+a_1)(b_0+b_1)=a_0b_0+ a_1b_0+a_0b_1 +a_1b_1 $ while $C_1=c_0+c_1=a_0b_0+ a_1b_0+a_0b_1 $, lacking the last term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial fact you are overlooking is:
$$ (a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2) \neq a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$

You need to fully distribute, as opposed to just multiplying term by term which is what you seem to want to do.

Comment: This is merely saying that  $c_n\neq a_nb_n$, rather than $C_n\neq A_nB_n,$ with the upper cases indicating partial sums.

Answer (score 4):

A correct equality is

$$ C_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} b_j, $$

which in general should differ from

$$ A_n B_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{\boxed{n}}} b_j $$

for obviously missing some terms.

Comment: I cannot parse the first equation, could you please give some further illustration? I believe in 3.48 Rudin has shown that $\sum{c_n}=\sum{a_n}\sum{b_n}$, but apparently he then says here that this doesn't necessarily hold for partial sums.

Comment: Guess I got the point… after checking the finite product term by term.